# Ignore Matlab Input Arguments

Tags: matlab, function, arguments

I have a function:

```
function myself(a,b,c,d)
```

I want to use this function inside a code by only giving arguments `a` and `b`. 
I want to ignore arguments `c` and `d`.

How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why is giving dummy variables not an option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [`varargin`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) and [`nargin`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html)

```
function output = myself(varargin)

if nargin > 0
    a = varargin{1};
    if nargin > 1
        b = varargin{2};
        if nargin > 2
            c = varargin{3};
            if nargin > 3
                d = varargin{4};
            end
        end
    end
end
```

You can also define default values this way:

```
function output = myself(varargin)

if nargin > 0
    a = varargin{1};
    if nargin > 1
        b = varargin{2};
        if nargin > 2
            c = varargin{3};
            if nargin > 3
                d = varargin{4};
            else
                d = 0;
            end
        else
            c = 0;
        end
    else
        b = 1;
    end
a = 50;
end
```

Note that many might choose to use [`switch`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) instead of `if, else`. That's a matter of personal preference.

```
function output = myself(varargin)

switch nargin
    case 1
        a = varargin{1};
    case 2
        [a, b] = varargin{:};   
    case 3
        [a, b, c] = varargin{:} 
    otherwise
        [a, b, c, d] = varargin{:};
end
```

Answer (score 3):

[Stewie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975660/1714410)'s answer is very good if you have many default arguments. However, if you only have one input that is not always used, you can check it specifically:

```
 function myself(a, b, c, d)
 if ~exist('d', 'var')
    %// d is not defined
 else
    %// you can use d here
 end
```

Comment: Nice addition =) I know it's easy to avoid, but do you know if executing your entire code inside an `if`-statment has any downsides? Formatting in comments is rubbish, but I'll give it a try: `function myfun(a,b,c,d) if ~exist('d', 'var') execute_long_and_complex_code; else return 0; end`?

Comment: @StewieGriffin why not reverse the condition? `if exist('d','var'), return 0; end; do_what_ever_you_like_here;`

Comment: @StewieGriffin I never checked for any downsides, but sometimes it's easier (for me at least) to use this `exist` check rather than enumerate `varargin`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Anyway, I think your code is good as an answer to that question because it helps understand the meaning of `varargin` and `nargin`.